# bootbox doesn't wait for confirmation

Tags: php, jquery, bootbox

I'm new on using bootbox plugin..

when I click on delete button it doesn't wait for bootbox confirmation.. it just executes my delete code...

Here's my code:

**JQUERY**

```
$('.cmd_delete_location').click(function(e){
$this=$(this);
bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function(result){
    if(result)
    {
        form = $this.parent();
        form.submit();
    }
});
});
```

**HTML**

```
 <form method="post">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" title="Update Location" value="<?=$loc['LocationID']?>" name="cmd_update_location"><i class="fa fa-edit fa-fw"></i></button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger cmd_delete_location" title="Delete Location" value="<?=$loc['LocationID']?>" name="cmd_delete_location"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-fw"></i></button>
 </form>
```

**PHP**

```
    if(isset($_POST['cmd_delete_location'])){
       // echo $LocationID = $this->input->post('hidden_id');
        $LocationID = $this->input->post('cmd_delete_location');
        $location_used_in_other_transaction = $this->main_m->get_where('temperaturelogs', array('LocationID' => $LocationID));
        if($location_used_in_other_transaction)
        {
            $_SESSION['type'] = "warning";
            $_SESSION['message'] = "Unable to Delete: Location is already used in other transaction!";
            redirect(current_url());
        }else{
            $this->main_m->delete_data('locations', array('LocationID' => $LocationID));
            $_SESSION['type'] = "success";
            $_SESSION['message'] = "Location's Successfully Deleted!";
            redirect(current_url());
        }
    }
```

thanks in advance..

Comment: may be you click before jquery load.

Comment: You defined buttons as `submit`, so when you click = form will send self to the server. Try to redefine buttons as `buttons` and then form submit will be available though `form.submit();` in your JS

Comment: @pes502 I did that but I can't get the value of the delete button....

Comment: @Jitendra is there a way for me to emulate the confirmation of bootbox like `onclick = return confirm('')`?

Comment: try add this to your JS: `$("#form_id").submit(function(){
  return false;
});` it will prevent to submit form, when you click on the submit button, `#form_id` is selector of your form, of course, so please edit this value

Comment: @pes502 it waits for the confirmation but the value in my button doesn't send to php.... x

Comment: @pes502 agree with your comment, because it is submit button, you need to change the type of input or use $('#form').submit(function(){ bootbox.confirm() })

Comment: I see.. I get it... thanks guys....